# Is it possible for multiple AWS Lambdas to service a single HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

On AWS, is it possible to have one HTTP request execute a Lambda, which in turn triggers a cascade of Lambdas running in serial, where the final Lambda returns the result to the user?

I know one way to achieve this is for the initial Lambda to "stay running" and orchestrate the other Lambdas, but I'd be paying for that orchestration Lambda to effectively do nothing most of the time, i.e. paying for the time it's waiting on the others. If it were non-lambda code, that would be like blocking (and paying for) an entire thread while the other threads do their work.

Unless AWS stops the billing clock while async Lambdas are "sleeping"/waiting on network IO?

Comment: AWS Step Functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as you've found only a single Lambda function can be invoked, this becomes an orchestrator.

This is not ideal but will have to be the case if you want to use multiple Lambda functions as you're serving a HTTP request, you can either use the Lambda to call a number of Lambda or instead create a [Step Function](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) which can can orchestrate the individual steps. You would still need the Lambda to start this, and then poll the status of it before returning the results.

Comment: I see, interesting, thanks! I guess one saving grace is I can use the lowest RAM setting -- 128MB -- on the orchestrator. I guess it needs to hold a heap throughout that whole time, so whilst I'm not getting my money's worth on CPU cycles, I am still paying for something I need, I guess :D

Comment: Yeah that will at least keep the costs down :)

Comment: you can invoke the step function directly from API Gateway...cuts down an 1 lambda

Comment: However, you won't get the response as it will simply [return the execution ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html). :(.